# "There comes a time when" vs. "It comes a time when"

Tags: phrase-choice

What are the differences between the two sentences below?

> 1. There comes a time when you have to fight for what you want.
> 2. It comes a time when you have to fight for what you want.

I usually use 'There comes a time when', but I often see 'It comes a time when' on the internet.

Comment: The first sentence is correct. The second is not correct UNLESS you mean to declaim (with a pause after "comes"): *It comes, a time when you have to fight for what you want.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only (1) is correct.

The pronoun "it" can only anticipate real, logical subjects (appearing after the verb) when these are infinitival, gerundial, or nominal clauses:

- **It**'s good **to fight** for what you want.
- **It**'s not worth **fighting** for what you want.
- **It**'s good **that** you have decided to fight for what you want.

Only the pronoun "there" can anticipate indefinite nouns or noun phrases:

- **There** comes **a time** when... (Here, "there" is the grammatical subject of the sentence.)

As an adverb of place, "there" can also be placed at the beginning of a sentence for emphasis. However, in this case "there" is NOT the grammatical subject. The grammatical subject only appears at the end as a result of a grammatical process known as "full inversion." Also notice that, in this case, the noun or noun phrase need not be indefinite:

- **There** comes **my train** at last!
- **There** comes **Mary**.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: Like Gustavson says, only use (1).

The long answer:
It is only (1) in standard English. However, they are interchangeable in various dialects. The difference between "There is/are" and "It is" is a dialectal. In non-standard English of the rural American South, one is typically going to hear "It is", as in "It's a storm coming through" for "There's a storm coming." "It's" replacing "There is/are" occurs in other English forms, to the extent that it is a grammatical rule in African-American English. The varieties are why you have come across it so much.

However, when using standard English, "it's" :) only one option that you can choose. The first one.